# How do I get rid of the clock in the menu-bar in Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, clock

I want to get rid of the clock menu display in Mac OSX. How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> and drag it out of the menu. If date and weekday are shown, they will also be removed.

Alternatively, you can disable and customize the clock in:
 *System Preferences → Date & Time → Clock.*

Comment: This option is not available for me: https://i.imgur.com/fZ4CnX1.png

Comment: This answer is outdated now.

Comment: clock not present in 12.3.1

Answer (score 6):

Now it's in System Preferences -> Dock & Menu Bar -> Menu Bar Only (section) -> Clock

However, as far as I can see, you cannot hide it anymore, that can be only done for the other items. What you can do, however, is to minimize to a small analogue watch, which takes minimum space

[image]

Comment: 2022. that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Go to -

**System Preferences → Date & Time → Clock** and **Uncheck** the show date and time in menu bar.

Done.

Comment: clock missing in latest update

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to hold down the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key on your keyboard and drag it out of the menu bar (you can also re-order the menu bar icons by holding the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key and dragging them around around, if you didn't know).

But, you can also go to  ** → System Preferences → Date & Time → Clock** and uncheck "Show date and time in menu bar" if you'd rather do it that way.

[image]

Comment: There is no Clock option in the latest update.